# rewrite from http to https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, ftp, dns

i have some weeks been struggeling with setting up my domain. First off there was problems to show my files under the wwwroot. That got fixed with this line of code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wwwroot/ 
RewriteRule (.*) /wwwroot/$1 [L]
```

Afterwords I found out that my domain not was a https. Therefore I enabled the SSL on my domain, and a person from the support said I had to add the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

But as I see it that is not working, and I really do not know how to solve this? I am thinking the two pieces of code has to be written together?

**Update**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wwwroot/ 
RewriteRule (.*) /wwwroot/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^apache-redirect-http-to-https\.html$ example.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That additional piece of code only redirect from `http://` to `https://` (and from `example.com` to `www.example.com`), but first you need to make https work when manually entering `https://www.example.com` in browser address bar

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^apache-redirect-http-to-https\.html$ https://www.yoursite.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html [R=301,L]

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Would that mean that my code has to look like this? (I have made an update on my question)